# image name is not saved as original image name using CarrierWave in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, carrierwave

I am using CarrierWave to upload images which will store into public -> uploads folder.

In my uploader.rb file, code structure is to give filename is like this,

```
def filename
"image.#{File.extname(original_filename).downcase}" if original_filename
end
```

But all images saved as images.jpg.
But i want to save image with original name like if i will upload image which contain name like car.jpg than image would be saved as car.jpg not as image.jpg in public -> uploads folder.

If any one knows about this issue, please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
def filename
    model.file_name
end
```

where file_name is the attribute on whatever you are uploading that contains the filename (if you want the extension, append it like you already do).

In your current code the file will be saved as 'image' (because you hardcoded "image.". You could also try

```
"#{original_filename}.#{File.extname(original_filename).downcase}" if original_filename
```

if original_filename is what you are expecting it to be).

Comment: What i have did after your suggestion is:  `def filename`
`"#{original_filename}" if original_filename`  `end`  And now it is saved as original file name only like if i will upload car.png it will store as original name i.e car.png.  Thanks for your help.